# Инвертировать бит в позиции с номером n ячейки А, если в ячейке В под номерами m, m+1 стоит последовательность из единиц

Tags: c++

Есть такое задание, нужно **инвертировать бит в позиции с номером n ячейки А, если в ячейке В под номерами m, m+1 стоит последовательность из единиц** в c++.

При этом ячейки A и B - имитация 16 разрядных регистров. Нумерация позиций (разрядов) ячеек с 0 – 15. Желательно в коде использовать команды "unsigned" и "void".
Заранее спасибо огромное за помощь!!

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((B>>m)&0x03==0x03) A ^= 1<<n;
```

Answer (score 0):

чтобы определить чему равен n-ый бит некоторого числа `value` необходимо выполнить

```
value & (1 << n)
```

если n-ый бит был равен 0, то значение описанной выше операции будет равно нулю иначе будет ненулевым (будет равно `1 << n` ну или `2^n`)

чтобы установить n-ый бит (установить бит в 1) необходимо выполнить:

```
value | (1 << n)
```

чтобы сбросить n-ый бит (установить бит в 0) необходимо выполнить:

```
value & (~(1 << n))
```

этого достаточно для выполнения задачи

Comment: Пожалуй, проверять пару битов в позициях `m, m+1`, что оба равны 1, лучше всего так:  `(((value >> m) & 3) == 3)`